# Regex with variable content

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write some kind of parser in PHP: it receives a text containing variables between `#*test-var*#`, e.g.: blabla #*test-var*# blabla
What I'm trying to do is to adjust this text so it becomes : `blabla <p>test-var</p> blabla`

On top of that, the type of variable can change, e.g.: `blabla #*:test-var*# blabla` should become something like: `blabla <div>test-var</div>`

(I've used some HTML simple tags here (e.g. the `<p>` tag) to explain it, but eventually this should become more advanced HTML)

Anyone got some suggestions?

Comment: SO allows you to use certain HTML tags to markup your question, so if you want them to appear as normal content, you should either use HTML entities, or preferably surround the tags with backticks (i.e. `) to mark them up as code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple regex will do.

```
$string = 'blah blah #*test-var*# blah blah';
$types = array(
    array(
        '/#\*(.*?)\*#/',
        '<p>$1</p>'
    ),
    array(
        '/#\*:(.*?)\*#/',
        '<div>$1</div>'
    )
);
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $string = preg_replace($type[0], $type[1], $string);
}
```

Edit: added support for multiple tags.

Comment: Well the thing is that the content of `#*....*#` identiefies the kind of output, so I'm afraid that won't work

Comment: Should use un-greedy flag in case they have multiple "tags" in a string.

Comment: @Brad Christie: There's a question mark in the expression; I'm pretty sure that kills greedy-ness.

Comment: Yea, poor verbage on my part. I agree with the answer and think it's the best fit (until I saw user485659's comment) but just more-so bringing light to the un-greedy flag for the sake of the original question. Getting close to 5:30 here--close to quitting time (think my mind has gotten a head-start)

Answer (score 0):

```
function some_kind_of_parser($input, $wrapper_tag='p', $wrapper_attributes='') {
  if ($wrapper_attributes == '')
    $open_tag = "<$wrapper_tag>";
  else
    $open_tag = "<$wrapper_tag $wrapper_attributes>";

  $close_tag ="</$wrapper_tag>";

  $regex = '/[^(?:#\*)]+#\*([^(#\*)]+)\*#[^(?:#\*)]+/';
  return preg_replace($regex, "$open_tag$1$close_tag", $input);
}

$test = 'blah blah #*test-var*# blah blah';

echo some_kind_of_parser($test); 
# => <p>test-var</p>

echo some_kind_of_parser($test, 'div', 'class="foo" id ="bar"');   
# => <div class="foo" id ="bar">test-var</div>
```